# Translating a SQL query containing a subquery into a GORM query in grails

Tags: sql, date, grails, subquery, grails-orm

I have the following domain name that I used on grails version 2.5.5

```
class OrderBook {    
  int orderNumber
  String mutationCode
  Date mutationDate
  User orderUser
  OrderStatus status
  OrderVendor vendor
  String catalogueNumber
  String orderDescription// (catalogue name) auto-completion from a vendor
  Float pricePerUnit
  Integer numberOfUnit
  float vat
  String orderUnit
  Float shipHandleCost
  Budget budget
  boolean reception
  String purchaseOrder
  String comment

  static constraints = {
    orderNumber      blank: false, unique:   false, display:false
    mutationCode     blank: false, inList:   ["c", "u", "d"], display:false //c: created, u:updated, d:deleted
    mutationDate     blank: false, display:  false 
    orderUser        blank: false, unique:   false
    status           blank: false, unique:   false
    vendor           blank: false, unique:   false
    catalogueNumber  blank: false, unique:   false
    orderDescription blank: false, unique:   false
    pricePerUnit     blank: false, unique:   false
    vat              blank: false, unique:   false
    orderUnit        blank: true,  nullable: true
    shipHandleCost   blank: false, unique:   false
    budget           blank: false, unique:   false
    purchaseOrder    blank: false, unique:   false
    comment          blank: true,  nullable: true, type: 'text'
  }
}
```

I wrote the following SQL request that work fine using `executeQuery`:

```
def orderBookLastList = be.vib.emone.OrderBook.executeQuery('''from OrderBook o where o.mutationDate in (select max(mutationDate) from OrderBook b where o.orderNumber=b.orderNumber) AND NOT o.mutationCode=:mutationDelete order by id''', [mutationDelete:'d'], [max: params.max, offset: params.offset])
```

I would like to write it in GORM style but I couldn't figure how to handle the subquery. I tried to use the WHERE but none of my trials worked.

Any tips will be welcome

Comment: Have a look at this way to handle subquery: https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#SubQuery You need to prepare subquery before and then use it in the `WHERE` clause of the actual query as it's used for `HAVING` clause in the example provided in this link.